# Manipulando lista de listas em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho uma lista assim:

```
 Lista_A = [['de','do','da','ou'],['ae','ay','yhh','oo'],['ow','pa','la','for']]
```

Como deixo ela assim:

```
Lista_A_new = ['de','do','da','ou','ae','ay','yhh','oo','ow','pa','la','for']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solução #1:**

```
Lista_A = [['de','do','da','ou'],['ae','ay','yhh','oo'],['ow','pa','la','for']]

Lista_A_new = [item for sublista in Lista_A for item in sublista]

print(Lista_A_new)
```

**Solução #2:**

```
Lista_A = [['de','do','da','ou'],['ae','ay','yhh','oo'],['ow','pa','la','for']]

Lista_A_new = sum( Lista_A, [] )

print(Lista_A_new)
```

**Solução #3:**

```
import numpy as np

Lista_A = [['de','do','da','ou'],['ae','ay','yhh','oo'],['ow','pa','la','for']]

Lista_A_new = np.concatenate(Lista_A)

print(Lista_A_new)
```

**Solução #4:**

```
import itertools

Lista_A = [['de','do','da','ou'],['ae','ay','yhh','oo'],['ow','pa','la','for']]

Lista_A_new = list(itertools.chain(*Lista_A))

print(Lista_A_new)
```

Answer (score 3):

Está a procura da função [`extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) que adiciona um iterável a uma lista. Para o aplicar precisa de utilizar um laço/ciclo que percorre as suas listas iniciais.

```
Lista_A = [['de','do','da','ou'],['ae','ay','yhh','oo'],['ow','pa','la','for']]

Lista_A_new  = []

for lista in Lista_A: #for percorre cada uma das sub listas iniciais
    Lista_A_new.extend(lista) #extend aqui adiciona todos os elementos de cada sub-lista

print(Lista_A_new) #['de', 'do', 'da', 'ou', 'ae', 'ay', 'yhh', 'oo', 'ow', 'pa', 'la', 'for']
```

[Veja o exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/kGtRwJ)

Aconselho também a que dê uma olhada as [convenções de escrita em python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), uma vez que os nomes de variáveis que utilizou não seguem a convenção.